# Performance Analysis in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, ubuntu, profiler

I have been programming in C++ with Visual Studio 2012 under Windows 7 and now I have switched to using Eclipse under Ubuntu.

In Visual Studio, there are great performance analysis tools and I'm looking for similar tools for Eclipse. After some Googling, I found gprof and it can tell approximately how much time each of my functions take.

However, there is a feature in Visual Studio which was useful which I could not find for Eclipse. Basically, knowing how much time a function has used overall is good, but I need to know how much time a function used when called from a certain line of code. To illustrate what I am looking for, consider [this image](http://pokit.org/get/?7978f70b28ec132c1e9b939a6d379916.jpg). From the picture, I can see line by line the amount of time spent.

Does anyone know a similar tool in Eclipse?

Thank you in advance,
Dave

Comment: Try google-perftools (gperftools) and/or `perf` utility from linux-tools. Both are more modern profilers for Linux. Line-by-line timing is called "code annotations". And there are some call-graph statistics in both profilers.

Comment: Please read [the Eclipse documentation on the subject](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Profiling/User_Guide).

Comment: Specifically, [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/User_Guides) contains everything you would ever want to know.

Comment: Thank you two for the responses. I am checking out these options and will report my success (or failure)!